# eclipse cdt use file from other projects

Tags: eclipse, reference, include, project, eclipse-cdt

I cannot find any clear answer for this. I hope it's quite basic.

So, I have a first project in Eclipse C/C++ with include files, cpp and compiled object files (*.o). What I want is to be able to use them in a second project, without duplicating them ?

Particularly, it would be nice to reference the object file, so I won't have to recompile them locally.

I added a reference to the first project in the settings, I also added the directory of the source file of the first project in the settings. So, if I just use and include file, it's fine, but if I'm trying to use a *.cpp file but by just including its *.hpp file, then it doesn't compile. It cannot finds reference to the functions declared in the *.hpp file.

So, is it possible ? If so, how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is good approach.

I think that you should consider creating a library. But this may lead you to have three projects:

- first project for the first application,
- second project for the second application,
- third project for the library which contains classes that are shared by the first and second application.

Comment: I think I found a solution, because I'm adding the directory of the source files in my other project in my current project, I think I will create a dummy cpp file that includes all the other cpp files that I might need. Stupid, but might work. And I don't plan to modify the other files, so, might avoid a recompilation every times!